# Iterating through key names from a PSCustomObject

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am writing a script for my site that utilizes a JSON configuration file. The JSON is similar to the following:

```
"Groups": {
    "GroupOne": {
        "NamingFilter": {
            "Not":"<SITE>-MJ*",
            "Has":"*WM,*WT"
        }
    },
    "GroupTwo": {
        "NamingFilter": {
            "Has":"<SITE>-MJ*, *WC,*WL"
        }
    },
    "GroupThree": {
        "NamingFilter": {
            "Not":"<SITE>-MJ*",
            "Has":"*WI"
        }
    }
}
```

To convert the object to something PowerShell can read, I use `ConvertFrom-Json` which converts it to type `PSCustomObject`.

I am at a point where I have to iterate over the `Groups` and get each group name to output them and their corresponding index within the configuration's `Groups` object. That is,

```
1. GroupOne
2. GroupTwo
3. GroupThree
```

The furthest I have gotten is:

```
foreach ($group in $configObject.Groups) {
    $group
}
```

And all this does is output something that looks like PowerShell array notation:

```
@{GroupOne=; GroupTwo=; GroupThree=;}
```

Is this even possible with a `PSCustomObject` type? I primarily code in JavaScript so perhaps I am oversimplifying (or overcomplicating it) the issue since this would be relatively easy.

Comment: Just a note - the JSON shown in the example needs a open "{" and closed "}" curly bracket around it to make it valid.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think I might have just figured it out thanks to the blog post *[Converting PsCustomObject To/From Hashtables](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timid/archive/2013/03/05/converting-pscustomobject-to-from-hashtables.aspx)*.

Using `Get-Member` and then `-MemberType` exposes each Group and then you just pull the:

```
foreach ($group in $configObject.Groups) {
    $groupName = $($group | Get-Member -MemberType *Property).Name
}
```

Outputs:

```
GroupOne
GroupTwo
GroupThree
```

I'm open to any other methods though.

### Update

I've found another way, but the only drawback is it doesn't use the fancy `ConvertFrom-Json` CmdLet. Instead it goes straight to the .NET library and uses its deserializer and converts it to a HashTable. This completely avoids having to muddle around with the PSCustomObject. IMO hashtables are a whole lot easier to work with.

```
$JSON = Get-Content -Path path/to.json -Raw
$HT = (New-Object System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer).Deserialize($JSON, [System.Collections.Hashtable])
$HT.Groups.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "$($_.Key) : $($_.Value)"
}
```

Comment: I haven't figured out the actual solution, but your solution doesn't actually enumerate through the object. This variation of your code: `foreach ($group in $configObject.Groups) {'--'; ($group | Get-Member -MemberType *Property).Name
}` will only output the `--` once; meaning it only passes through the loop one time. POSH 4.0

Comment: I found an posted the solution. Hope it helps others. :)

Answer (score 32):

### Solution

I'm not sure how early of a version you can do this with, but it works for me in PowerShell 5.1... Feel free to give it a try in earlier versions:

```bsh
$ipinfo = Invoke-WebRequest 'http://ipinfo.io/json' -UseBasicParsing | ConvertFrom-Json
foreach ($info in $ipinfo.PSObject.Properties) {
    $info.Name
    $info.Value
    '--' # <-- Seeing this double hash proves we're iterating fully.
}
```

#### Outputs

```
ip
1.2.3.4
--
hostname
No Hostname
--
city
Denton
--
region
Texas
--
country
US
--
loc
33.2148,-97.1331
--
org
AS589 University of North Texas
--
postal
76203
--
```

*This is all done with PowerShell 4.0; `ConvertTo-Json` and `ConvertFrom-Json` were introduced in PowerShell 3.0; I haven't tested PowerShell 3.0 or 5.0.*

---

### Another Example

Try it for yourself with another example:

```bsh
$ipinfo = ConvertFrom-Json (Invoke-WebRequest 'http://ipinfo.io/json' -UseBasicParsing)
foreach ($info in ($ipinfo.PSObject.Members | ?{ $_.MemberType -eq 'NoteProperty'})) {
    $info.Name
    $info.Value
    '--'
}
```

#### Outputs

```
ip
1.2.3.4
--
hostname
No Hostname
--
city
Denton
--
region
Texas
--
country
US
--
loc
33.2148,-97.1331
--
org
AS589 University of North Texas
--
postal
76203
--
```

---

[This and other PowerShell looping are available on my blog](http://blog.vertigion.com/2015/11/18/looping-through-objects/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=answer&utm_campaign=powershell#psobject).