# Can't edit value of PSCustomObject from ConvertFrom-Json

Tags: json, powershell

I am trying to divide every value of a JSON object by 1000 in powershell, this is my script,

```
$logs = Get-Content $file

$json = $logs | ConvertFrom-Json

for($i=0;$i -lt $json.timestamp.Count; $i++)
{
     $json.timestamp[$i]=$json.timestamp[$i]/1000
}
```

The script runs without any errors, but when I check `$json.timestamp`, none of the values have changed. Is this a special object as I've converted it from JSON?

Example of JSON:

```json
{"timestamp":1459786417821000192,"zoneId":23919643}
```

Comment: Can you provide us a test file to reproduce ?

Comment: Please post a *representative* sample. The JSON string you posted doesn't have any array elements. Also, why would you want to divide a timestamp by 1000 in the first place?

Comment: well, it's a terrible situation to be in, but I am using a log management product called Splunk, which only supports micro seconds and not nano seconds, so I need to convert the value to microseconds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indices are wrong. You loop over `$json` but you are using the indices on the properties. Use this instead:

```
for($i=0;$i -lt $json.timestamp.Count; $i++)
{
     $json[0].timestamp=$json[0].timestamp/1000
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, that worked, thank you. But what I don't understand is why $json[0].timestamp and $json.timestamp[0] still outputs the same value when I use it in my script ? Why the difference when I attempt to set a new value to it ?

Comment: @rusty009 Weird, didn't see that first. I only took a look at your code and was like "Hmm, the indices are wrong". Seems like some strange behaviour of  PSCustomObject, but I couldn't find anything about this on the web. Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18779762/iterating-through-key-names-from-a-pscustomobject) or the link in there can give you some help.